# How to use javascript conditions correctly?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a slider function, which works perfectly fine with `moveRight()` but I am stuck, and can use it only once.

I decided to use a condition to disable the move function and change the attributes of links on the second click. My code below:

```
$('#control_next').click(function () {
    var used = 0;
    if (used == 0) {
        moveRight();
        used = 1;
    } else if (used == 1) {
        $('.control_next').attr('href', '#business-events');
        $('.control_next').addClass( "url" );
    }  
    alert(used);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to place the varaible `used` outside your event handler because else it will always be 0 with every click:

```
var used = 0;

$('#control_next').click(function () {
     if (used == 0) {
        moveRight();
        used = 1;
     }
     else if (used == 1) {
        $('.control_next').attr('href', '#business-events');
        $('.control_next').addClass( "url" );
     }  
     alert(used);
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, both answers helped equally. +1 for reasoning.

-Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You should declare variable Globally. Like

```
var used = 0;
$('#control_next').click(function () {
     if (used == 0) {
        moveRight();
        used = 1;
     }
     else if (used == 1) {
        $('.control_next').attr('href', '#business-events');
        $('.control_next').addClass( "url" );
     }  
});
```